# Request method 'POST' not supported with Spring and Vue.js when enter key is pressed

Tags: java, spring-boot, vue.js, jsp, post

I have this problem. When I click on the search button the code works fine, but when I press enter an HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException throws. I know I don't have a POST controller, but I don't need it at any time for the search button. What I am missing?

```
<form method="post" @keypress.enter="search">
        <div class="card mb-3">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4 required">
                        <label for="id">Id</label>
                        <input type="text" v-model="model.id" name="id" id="id" class="form-control" maxlength="50" >
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <button type="button" id="btnSearch" class="btn btn-primary" @click="search">
                    <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    Search
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Well? You have two `@GetMapping`s and haven't showed any `@PostMapping`.

Comment: Yeah, if you click the search button the code works fine, even without de @PostMapping. The error just throws then you press enter key instead of hit the button. So why one request it and the other one not?

Comment: Always start debugging at boundaries. In this case, that means the REST request between your browser and the backend. Inspect your browser's Network tab, confirm that the request is being sent to the server as you expect, and use tools like curl or Postman to talk to the server directly and get it to do what you want.

Comment: Try to split your code into different files. Which part is the JSP, and which is the Java Controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add attribute `@keypress.enter.prevent` in your `input` field